# convert async to Rx.js

Tags: javascript, mongodb, rxjs

So, we are trying to rewrite our `express` server into `Rx`. It is currently using `async` for all stream operations. The code looks like the following:

```
var async = require('async');

function getCountAndChannels(name, cb){
    var tasks = [
        function(cb) {
             //does a mongoDB search and returns count
        },
        function(cb) {
            //does a findOne mongoDB search and returns 
        }
    ];
    async.parallel(tasks, cb);
}

router.get('data', function(req, res) { //router is the express router
    var recorders = req.query.recorders.split(',');

    async.map(recorders, function(name, cb) {
        getCountAndChannels(name, cb);
    }, function(err, countsAndChannels) {
        if(err) throw err;

        // here countsAndChannels is an array with first element the count
        // and second element the document.

        // do other async stuff based on the results

        res.status(200).json('send some calculations');
});
```

The thing here I have to do is loop over the array of `recorders` and for each one calculate the two mongoDB searches. I have tried using `Rx.Observable.merge` which doesn't return the results in an array but in 2 different calls of the callback. So, then I tried `Rx.Observable.zip` which I believe is what I'm looking for.

The problem is I don't know how to loop over the `recorders` and send the result when all operations are finished. Because a simple `forEach` loop will throw a `Cannot set headers after they are sent` error.

This is what I have so far:

```
recorders.forEach(recorder => {        
    Rx.Observable.zip([
        search1,
        search2
    ]).subscribe(
        (countsAndChannels) => {                
            // do stuff
            res.send('the results');
        },
        err => res.status(500).json(err),
        () => res.send('OK')
    );  
});
```

Haven't used Rx before, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: A huge list of alternative of operators from async.js in Rx http://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/mappingr_rxjs_from_different_libraries/async/index.html

Comment: @xgrommx thanks! i didn't find this article before while searching. will take a look

Comment: thanks again @xgrommx ! It helped me solve the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to convert your list of recorders to an Observable stream, then `flatMap` over each recorder (ie perform your async processing), then call `toArray` to store all the results into an array:

```
var recorder$ = Rx.Observable.from(recorders);
var countsAndChannels$ = recorder$
    .flatMap(performAsyncTask);

// allResults$ will emit once all of the async work is complete
var allResults$= countsAndChannels$.toArray();

allResults$.subscribe(results => {
    // Send response to client;
});
```

Comment: thanks, solved it already but I will try your solution as well.